# saving excel as pdf in active directory

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code to save a specific excel worksheet in a specific location. I'd like to change the code in order to save in the same directory that the file was originally opened in. Currently it's set to save in my C:\ but if I had opened the file from a different directly, I would like it saved there.

```
Sheets("Lease Charts").Activate
With Sheets("Lease Charts")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Temp " & Format(Range("L1"), "mm-dd-yyyy"), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Just you `ThisWorkbook.Path` Like so:

```
With Sheets("Lease Charts")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp " & Format(Range("L1"), "mm-dd-yyyy"), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by just removing the specific directory from the filename !

```
Sheets("Lease Charts").Activate
With Sheets("Lease Charts")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="Temp " & Format(Range("L1"), "mm-dd-yyyy"), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Comment: That will use the "current directory" as returned by `CurDir()` but that will *not necessarily* be the same folder as the workbook running your code.  Scott's answer is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the precision.